# Handling Exceptions on requests

Tags: python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I have a bunch of URL's (over 50k) in a CSV file from different Newspapers. I primarily looking for the main headline `<h1>` and the main paragraphs `<p>`.
I'm getting an exception that I'm not quite familiar with or don't know how to handle. Her is the message I get back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x118e1a6a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.cnn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2019/02/01/us/chicago-volunteer-homeless-cold-trnd/index.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+rss%2Fcnn_topstories+%28RSS%3A+CNN+-+Top+Stories%29 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x118e1a6a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/FELIPE/english_news/pass_news.py", line 24, in <module>
    request_to_url = requests.get(urls).text
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 640, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 640, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 218, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.cnn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2019/02/01/us/chicago-volunteer-homeless-cold-trnd/index.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+rss%2Fcnn_topstories+%28RSS%3A+CNN+-+Top+Stories%29 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x118e1a6a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)))
```

Her is the code:

```
import uuid
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

csv_file = os.path.join(cwd, "csv_data", "data.csv")

text_data = os.path.join(cwd, "raw_text2")

if not os.path.exists(text_data):
    os.makedirs(text_data)

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)


for link, source in df.iterrows():
    urls = source['Link']
    source_name = source["Source"]
    request_to_url = requests.get(urls).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request_to_url, 'html.parser')
    try:
        h = soup.find_all('h1')

        try:
            text_h = h.get_text()
        except AttributeError:
            text_h = ""

        p = soup.find_all('p')
        text_p = ([p.get_text() for p in soup('p')])
        text_bb = str(" ".join(repr(e) for e in text_p))

        source_dir = os.path.join(text_data, source_name)

        try:
            os.makedirs(source_dir)
        except FileExistsError as e:
            pass

        filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
        write = open(os.path.join(source_dir, filename + ".txt"), "w+", encoding="utf-8")
        write.write(text_h + "\n" + text_bb)
        write.close()

        data = pd.Series(text_h + text_bb)
        with open("raw_text.csv", "a") as f:
            data.to_csv(f, encoding="utf-8", header=False, index=None)

    except:
        # Removes all <div> with id "sponsor-slug"
        for child_div in soup.find_all("div", id="sponsor-slug"):
            child_div.decompose()

        # Remove all <p> with class "copyright"
        for child_p in soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': "copyright"}):
            child_p.decompose()

        # Removes all <a> tags an keeps the content if any
        a_remove = soup.find_all("a")
        for unwanted_tag in a_remove:
            unwanted_tag.replaceWithChildren()

        # Removes all <span> content and keeps content if any
        span_remove = soup.find_all("span")
        for unwanted_tag in span_remove:
            unwanted_tag.replaceWithChildren()

        # Removes all <em> content and keeps content if any
        span_remove = soup.find_all("em")
        for unwanted_tag in span_remove:
            unwanted_tag.replaceWithChildren()
```

What is the best way of handling these exceptions?
Is it possible to ignore the connection if not possible and go to the next URL?

I want to crawl and add the content into another CSV file or add them to the current CSV if possible. At the same time create different folders with the different sources and add the corresponding text to that folder.

Its basically what this code is doing:

```
        filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
        write = open(os.path.join(source_dir, filename + ".txt"), "w+", encoding="utf-8")
        write.write(text_h + "\n" + text_bb)
        write.close()

        data = pd.Series(text_h + text_bb)
        with open("raw_text.csv", "a") as f:
            data.to_csv(f, encoding="utf-8", header=False, index=None)
```

I want to use NLP on each text and later try to use some sentiment analyzing tools on the text.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting the **text** value of response, in this line:

```
request_to_url = requests.get(urls).text
```

You can check if link is available or NOT. I wrote simple function for this action:

```
import requests

# Open session
s = requests.Session()

page_url = "http://wp.meQ/testBadUrl" # example of bad URL

def get_response(page_url):
    """ Get good or bad response from page_url"""
    # Create 'bad' Response object
    bad_resp = requests.Response()
    bad_resp.status_code = 404
    try:
        # By default 'allow_redirects' = True
        good_resp = s.get(page_url, timeout=(3, 10))
        if good_resp.ok:
            return good_resp
        else:
            return bad_resp
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Exception! Bad Request for URL: " + page_url)
        return bad_resp
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print("Exception! Timeout for URL: " + page_url)
        return bad_resp
    except:
        print("Unknown Exception!: " + page_url)
        return bad_resp

page_resp = get_response(page_url)

if page_resp.ok:
    # Your code for good URLs
    print("Append URL into 'GOOD' list")
else:
    # Your code for bad URLs
    print("Skip BAD url here...")
```

You can also add and handle different requests exceptions (full list [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py)), if you need.
I hope it will help you.